# How to configure jackson property naming strategy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-rest

This code does not work:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestMvcConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    ...

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = super.objectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return mapper;
    }

    ...
}
```

How to configure Jackson property naming strategy with JavaConfig?

Comment: What does _does not work_ mean?

Comment: For anyone using latest Jackson, use `PropertyNamingStrategies` instead of `PropertyNamingStrategy`. I spent far to long trying to figure out why `PropertyNamingStrategy` was deprecated and what to replace it with.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Solution:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestMvcConfig extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {
    ...

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = super.objectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return mapper;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public ObjectMapper halObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = super.halObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return mapper;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why does that make a difference?

Comment: I'm added propertyNamingStrategy to halObjectMapper(). defaultMessageConverters() used halJacksonHttpMessageConverter() and jacksonHttpMessageConverter() for configure messageConverters.

Comment: I don't see how that's in any way related to your question though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use below approach for naming strategy :

```
class MyBean {
     private String inReply;
     public void setInReplyToUserId(String s) { 
       inReply = s; 
     }
     public String getInReplyToUserId() { 
       return inReply; 
     }
  }

  class MyNaming extends PropertyNamingStrategy {
    @Override
    public String nameForGetterMethod(MapperConfig<?> config,
         AnnotatedMethod method, String defaultName)
    {
      // Replace underscore+letter with upper-case(letter)
      // (left as exercise to reader!)
      return convertName(defaultName);
    }
  }

  objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new MyNaming());
```