# Spring MVC Framework, Controller request parameters bind from LowerCase with underscores to CamelCase

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am a little bit confused about Spring MVC controller parameters binding.

Like the following code:

```html
@RestController
public class TestRequestParamController {

    @GetMapping("request")
    public Param get(Param param) {
        return param;
    }

}

public class Param {

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String phone;

    private String addressNumber;

    private String address;
    // getter and setter...
}
```

`curl -X GET "http://localhost:8080/request?phone_number=123123"`

How can I request this **phone_number** to my controller and bind **phone_number** to **phoneNumber**?

One way I know is to use **@RequestParam** annotation,
but if there is a lof of parameters, and each parameter needs to use it(RequestParam), it seems to duplicate and not very good.

Thus, use a class instead of putting each parameter to method parameters parentheses will be better, but I can't figure out how to bind it.

Comment: The actual mapping is most likely handled by Jackson, so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36970807/how-to-configure-jackson-property-naming-strategy

Comment: you can bind to a model, any serialized object, and as far as you have getters/setters for all attributes, Spring will populate from your request

Comment: Thank you guys. I will try what u have said.

Comment: Hi @E Cai, were you able to solve this problem? Currently on the same situation :D